# in sources in browser show me old js file not the updated one

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome

so basically in source files in chrome browser, it is saved an old js file not the updated one . no matter what I change it does not update .
I just started with firebase and do not know if the problem is with that . So how can I update files in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

What do you use to serve your app? Maybe it cached the js file and it is not updating the cache.

Comment: I use firebase serve.  If I change anything in html or use script tags in html it works fine

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;-)